# How to Import or link CSV with more than 255 fields in ACCESS?

Tags: excel, vba, csv, ms-access, import

I have a .csv with more than 255 fields (395 exactly), I only need 3 fields but **I cannot manipulate the source file** manually, that is, I cannot divide it in two.
The fields are: 131, 208 and 282

I have tried to do it by wizard but Access won't let me do it because it has more than 255 fields.
I have tried a thousand ways with vba but have not been successful.

Is there a way to do it with vba?

Answer (score 2):

Tough luck, Access has no built-in way to access anything with over 255 columns. That's a hard limit.

Your options are:

1. Open the file in Excel, remove the columns you don't want to import, save a copy, import the copy, delete the copy (possibly all done in VBA).
2. Through VBA, open the file in Excel, and write the desired content to a table row by row using a recordset.
3. Use (or create) a VBA CSV parser. There's an MIT-licensed CSV parser [here](https://github.com/sdkn104/VBA-CSV) (not affiliated).

Since all of these are too broad to cover in depth, I'll leave it at that.

Answer (score 0):

*Hope this is what you were looking for*

```
'----------
Function Test123()
   ReSize_MyFile "C:\MyFolder\", "File_A.csv", "C:\MyFolder\", "File_B.csv", ",", _
                 "131; 208; 282"
End Function

'----------
Public Function ReSize_MyFile(pFrPath As String, pFrFile As String, _
                              pToPath As String, pToFile As String, _
                              pDelimType As String, pFldList As String) As String
'-- This method will work for both ".csv" and ".txt" file types.
    Dim strTxLine1 As String
    Dim strTxLine2 As String
    Dim arrFldMain As Variant
    Dim arrFldList As Variant
    Dim intCnt1    As Integer

    On Error GoTo ERR_RTN

    Open pFrPath & pFrFile For Input As #1
    Open pToPath & pToFile For Output As #2
    
    arrFldList = Split(pFldList & ";", ";")

    Do Until EOF(1)
        strTxLine2 = ""

        Line Input #1, strTxLine1

        arrFldMain = Split(strTxLine1 & pDelimType, pDelimType)

        For intCnt1 = LBound(arrFldList) To UBound(arrFldList)
            If (Val(arrFldList(intCnt1) & "") > 0) And _
               (Val(arrFldList(intCnt1) & "") <= UBound(arrFldMain) + 1) Then
                strTxLine2 = strTxLine2 & IIf(strTxLine2 = "", "", pDelimType) & _ 
                             arrFldMain(Val(arrFldList(intCnt1) & "") - 1)
            End If
        Next intCnt1

        If (strTxLine2 > "") Then
            Print #2, strTxLine2
        End If
    Loop    'EOF(1)

EXIT_RTN:
    On Error Resume Next
    Close #1
    Close #2

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function

ERR_RTN:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "[ReSize_MyFile]"
    Resume EXIT_RTN
End Function    'ReSize_MyFile
```